# How do I hide a range of rows by getting the start and end row values from user input cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet of 1,000 plus rows.

I'm trying to hide all rows that match the values I input into cells A1 (the starting row in the range), and cell A2 (the end row in the range).

```vb
Sub Macro1()
'
' Hide rows when row numbers are between the values in cell A1 and Cell A2.
'
'   Range("A1:A15").Select 'Trying to modify this so that I get values from Cells A1 and A2.
    Rows(Range("A1").Value:Range("A2").Value).Select ' This is my failed attempt.
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to hide the rows from the value in A1 to the rows in the value in A2?  i.e. A1 = 10 and A2 = 25?  Which means you hide rows 10 to 25?

Comment: Perhaps you don't yet know about "Record Macro"? (Bottom left of main Excel window, or, In the Developer Tab.) It's not perfect, but it's often a quick way to find an object or function. Record a macro, then inspect the code generated. Keep in mind you seldom need to select something to work with it (macro recording always does this and it's unnecessary).

Comment: Hi Skin. Yes. Exactly right.

Thank you Stax. I use the record macro quite a lot. The problem is that recording macros gives fixed row numbers such as, let's say rows 5 to 20. In my case, I want to be able to change the row numbers, by inputting their values in cells A1 and A2, and then "get"-ing these values into the macro's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment, I'm going to assume you want to hide the rows (inclusive) between the two values you specify in **A1** and **A2**.

You'll need to clean it up to make sure the correct sheet is having this applied to it.  Right now, it works on the active sheet.

I've also assumed that if you change the numbers, you want to unhide all of the previously hidden rows.

```
Public Sub HideRows()
    Dim lngRowFrom As Long, lngRowTo As Long, objSheet As Worksheet
    
    Set objSheet = ActiveSheet
    
    With objSheet
        On Error GoTo ErrorCatchNotNumeric

        lngRowFrom = .Range("A1").Value
        lngRowTo = .Range("A2").Value
        
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If lngRowFrom > .Rows.Count Or lngRowFrom < 1 Then GoTo ErrorCatchNotNumeric
        If lngRowTo > .Rows.Count Or lngRowTo < 1 Then GoTo ErrorCatchNotNumeric
        
        If lngRowFrom > lngRowTo Then
            MsgBox "Your ""From"" row is greater than your ""To"" row.", vbCritical, "Error"
        Else
            .Rows.Hidden = False
            .Rows(lngRowFrom & ":" & lngRowTo).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorCatchNotNumeric:
    MsgBox "The values you supplied are not valid!", vbInformation, "Error"
    
End Sub
```

Adapt it as you see fit.

Comment: Skin. This is awesome! Thank you. I'll test it this afternoon. I'm sure it is exactly what I need. :-)

Comment: Tested, and it works great. Thank you. :-)